# Try/try catch function in R

Tags: r

How can i use the try/try catch function in R to proceed to next loop and do sys.sleep for 60 seconds if the trycatch/try function returns an error. ANy help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
for (x in list(1,2,"a",4,5)){
  print(x)
  y <- try( x+1) # maybe you want try(x+1,silent=TRUE)
  if(inherits(y, "try-error")) Sys.sleep(5) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it was really helpful :)