# Moving to next value in list if error occurs in for loop

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

Hi Guys I'm fairly new to R and tried to look at past examples of tryCatch and I was sadly not able to understand it and apply it to my problem.

So I have the following code

```
for(i in context.stocks){


  B = as.zoo(av_get(symbol = i, av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", interval = "1min", outputsize = "full"))
  A =merge.zoo(A,B)
```

Where context.stocks is a large list (497 values) of tickers, some of which cause errors with the data-call and I'd like the loop to continue even if there is an error with one of the tickers.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r it is really well described

Comment: If you also want to think about just a `try()` rather than `tryCatch()`, see [this passage](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling) in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book or [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416163/try-try-catch-function-in-r).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at it.